# Learning Android SDK using only Android API examples

Tags: java

I keep reading that I have to learn Java to make android programs.  But when I read about Java, none of it applies to the modules in the Android SDK.  I am not much of a programer so if I have to spend years trying to learn another language and mess with other compilers before Android SDK will look like something that can be done, I'm not intrested.  This should be an easy request, but when I asked on IRC they were very rude.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot possibly program Android without knowing Java. I suppose you could try learning both at the same time, but that will be quite a steep learning curve. The android-samples won't make any sense to you if you don't understand Java.

sorry, there are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert, but I studied the basics of Java a couple of years ago in college and then went on to use Android for my bachelor thesis project (this was back when the newest Android version was 1.6 IIRC). In my limited experience, Android SDK modules indeed have very little to do with Java. In any case, it felt like I was learning a completely new language and SDK. In my opinion, you'll be fine learning Android by itself. I would suggest you give it a shot, and if you find yourself stuck at some point you can always take a step back and get a book on Java.

Also, since you mention you're not much of a programmed, Google had a project called App Inventor last year that non-programmers could use to make simple Android apps. I've never used it but I've heard great things about it, so depending on your project you might want to check it out. Google has since dropped support for it, but it seems MIT has picked it up: http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/.

Edit: fixed link.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I still need some help finding material based on the Android SDK to learn from.

Comment: What about the Dev Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html? For my purposes, I didn't need more than that and the tutorials on the site to get a grasp on Android. And I think I didn't even read the entire thing. Be sure to take a loot at the sample code as well after you've completed the tutorials, it goes into more detail than the tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample.